# I have a csv file with "" between each field . How do I extract into excel

Tags: excel, csv

I have a file in csv where the fields in a record are separated by double speech marks.

For example

> ""field1""field2""field3"

What can I do in excel to format these into the normal fields you get in excel?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open a new empty spreadsheet in Excel
2. Go to the Data tab and select 'From Text'
3. Select the file you want to open
4. Choose the 'Delimited' option and click Next
5. Select the correct delimiter which will display the metadata correctly in the Preview pane below